# Wrong Sum formula: displaying 1,73472E-17 instead of 0

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Office 365 32-bit

I'm getting 1,73472E-17 for the SUM formula when it should be zero.
Not sure how it gets to this number.

The numbers are (in A1:A12)
0 0,05 0,09 0 0 0 0 -0,12 -0,02 0 0 0
In A13 the result of the sum is 1,73472E-17

[Cell A13 shows wrong SUM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V622y.png)

Comment: Floating point arithmetic is usually not exact.  So, you might not get exactly zero as the sum, even though you expect it.

Comment: Please read this article: https://support.microsoft.com/en-sg/help/214118/how-to-correct-rounding-errors-in-floating-point-arithmetic